# How do I add Profile Photos to Authenticated User Accounts in Firebase / Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have read the Firebase Docs for "Managing Users" for web, I have also watched the video on their YouTube channel.

However, when I try to implement the code they show, I am receiving this error: "Property 'afAuth' does not exist on type HTML element." &
"Property 'afStorage' does not exist on type HTML element."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular'; 
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.page.scss'],
})
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
firstName = this.firstName;
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private navCtrl: NavController, private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ProfilePic() {
    var uploader = document.getElementById('upload')
    var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');
    fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = 'e.target.files[0];'
    var user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
    var storageRef = this.afStorage.ref(user + '/profilePicture/' + file) 
    var task = storageRef.put(file);
    })          

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access the AugularFireAuth object inside the callback for the event listener.

I will advise you have the call back return the image, then have another method save the image to the firebase profile of the user